# jQuery multiple handlers for the same element & event how to distinguish between them

Tags: jquery

I'm attaching a handler to an element which is more than likely has another handler for the very same event. When done I want to remove just my handler. How do I do that?

Here's how I register my event handler:

```
$(document).on("click", function(){ ... });
```

and here's how in theory you unregister the handler, it just sounds a bit scary to do it this way:

```
$(document).off("click"); // is it safe, can other handlers get spoiled as a result of calling it???
```

Comment: how is the event registered and where is the remove code?

Comment: *"When done.."* - when what is done?

Comment: If only there was [a place you could look](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to find out how to use `.off()` for this purpose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like

```
var handler = function(){
}

el.on('event', handler);
//to remove
el.off('event', handler)
```

Comment: Any chance I can do it w/out using function vars as I use anonymous function most times, can event namespaces be employed here somehow?

Comment: Yes, event namespaces can do the job with anonymous functions. Did you read [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/off/) yet?